# validate an XML based on an XSD and throw all errors at once in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xsd, perl-module

I am trying to validate an XML based on a XSD. Below is the part of the code where i am validating the xml against xsd:

```
my $schema = XML::LibXML::Schema->new(location => $xsd);
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;

my $doc = $parser->parse_file($xml);
eval { $schema->validate( $doc ) };

if ( my $ex = $@ ) {
    return $ex;
}
```

The code works fine but if the xml is not validated it gives me an error once i fix the issue in the xml and rerun the code i get different set of errors i just want to know if there is any way i can print all the validation errors at once?

I have even tried the solution given by @Paulo SantAnna  in the below link:
[Perl XML::LibXML::Schema will stop validation on first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206672/perl-xmllibxmlschema-will-stop-validation-on-first-error) 
but even this didn't work.

Comment: @simbabque I think he's trying to report all errors in an XML document instead of just the first one. I imagine some tools stop at the first error, which forces you into a fix-validate-repeat cycle when you have multiple errors in your XML.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yeah that makes sense. But if the document is broken, you cannot really continue parsing. An HTML linter like the W3 validator can do that because HTML is a more forgiving spec, but I don't see any proper XML parser continue parsing after for example not finding the end of the root node. Oh but then again, we don't want to parse. We want to validate. Still, apparently they tried one, so my comment is valid. We need to see which one, and how, or the question is off-topic.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you got my question this is exactly i wanted to ask probably i should i phrased my question in a better way.

Comment: Great. That's much better. Can you maybe also include an example XML and XSD file? I'd like to try something, but I don't want to go look for examples or roll my own. My XSD skills are a bit rusty. ;)